# How to merge two column which are already exist in one datatable?

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datacolumn

I have one datatable. In that table I have columns named [Total Day], [Present day], and [leave].
Data are as follows:

```
[Total Day], [Present day], [leave]
   30           25             5
   30           26             4
```

Now i want to concatenate those three columns in one another column. I want output something like this:

```
[Total Day] [Present Day] [Leave]  [TotalDay    PresentDay  Leave]
30           25             5      30 VBCrLf    25 VBCrLf     5
30           26             4      30 VBCrLf    26 VBCrLf     4
```

Comment: This is asp.net net. Do you want vbCrLf for the delimiter, or <br/>?

Comment: Do you want to do this in the database or the client code?

Comment: joel-coehoorn and Oded i want to do in code behind not in Database side and between that i want one VbCrLf or <br/> anything but i want it for PDF print so that in pdf i pring each value in new line in same cell....

Comment: Please friend Help me out .. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table.Columns.Add("TotalDay    PresentDay  Leave", GetType(String), "[Total Day] + '" & vbCrLf & "' + [Present Day] + '" & vbCrLf & "' + [Leave]")
```

Assuming that the square brackets are not part of the column name, if they are, use "[[Total Day\]]" etc. For details, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Total Day], [Present Day], [Leave], 
       [Total Day] + '\n' + [Present Day] + '\n' + [Leave] As [TotalDay PresentDay Leave]
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Issue is in Code Behind DataTable class.